# Regex to replace a word that is not enclosed between tags (non-html)

Tags: php, xml, regex

Limited regex experience, I'm working in PHP with preg_replace.

I want to replace a specified "word" that is NOT between the [no-glossary] ... [/no-glossary] tags. My expression works if their are not spaces between the "word" and tags, or if their is a space after the "word", but if I put a space (exepected) before the word it fails!

These work:

```
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary]this[/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary]this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';
```

This doesn't:

```
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';
```

Pattern used explained part-by-part

```
/                      - find
(?<!\[no-glossary\])   - Not after the [no-glossary] tag
[ ]*                   - Followed by 0 or more spaces (I think this is the problem)
\b(this)\b             - The word "this" between word boundaries
[ ]*                   - Followed by 0 or more spaces
(?!\[\/no-glossary\])  - Not before the [/no-glossary] tag
/
```

Here is the code:

```
$pattern = "/(?<!\[no-glossary\])[ ]*\b(this)\b[ ]*(?!\[\/no-glossary\])/"; 
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, "that", $html);

print $html;
```

Output:

```
<p>Do not change [no-glossary] that [/no-glossary] changethat.</p>
```

Problems:

1. word was changed between tags.
2. space removed in front of the second word that was correctly replaced.

Comment: Thanks for editing this for me Brad.

Answer (score 3):

Just capture white spaces:

```
$subject = <<<LOD
<p>Do not replace [no-glossary]this[/no-glossary] replace this.</p>
<p>Do not replace [no-glossary]this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>
<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this[/no-glossary] replace this.</p>
<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>
LOD;
$pattern = '`(?<!\[no-glossary])( *+)\bthis\b( *+)(?!\[/no-glossary])`';
echo $subject.'<br/>';
echo preg_replace($pattern,"$1rabbit$2",$subject); ?>
```

Comment: Wow. You must be a geniac!! I thought the $1 and $2 was a typo, but it works. Are these placeholders for the blank spaces before and after the target word?

Comment: @user2254788 Yes $1 and $2 are respectively the content of the first and the second capture groups, who matches blank spaces ( *+)

Comment: This won't work correctly if `Do not replace this[/no-glossary] replace this.` or `Do not replace [no-glossary]this replace this.`. @user2254788 If it doesn't matter just use this solution !

Comment: One more quick (last) question. What are the grave accents (`) in the pattern do?

Comment: @user2254788 Instead of using `/` as delimiter, he used `\``, basically you could also use `#` or `~` etc... as delimiter !

Answer (score 3):

After playing a little bit with the RegEx pattern, I found out that the Regex PCRE engine has some limits, so I took the problem from another perspective:

1. Match all `[no-glossary] this [/no-glossary]` and `this`.
2. Filter the results.

This can be done with `preg_replace_callback()`:

**PHP 5.3+ required**:

```
$pattern = "/\[no-glossary\][ ]*\bthis\b[ ]*\[\/no-glossary\]|this/"; 
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';

$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match){
    if($match[0] == 'this'){
        return('that');
    }else{
        return($match[0]);
    }
}, $html);

print $html;
```

**If you aren't running PHP 5.3+ :**

```
$pattern = "/\[no-glossary\][ ]*\bthis\b[ ]*\[\/no-glossary\]|this/"; 
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';

$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'replace_function', $html);

function replace_function($match){
    if($match[0] == 'this'){
        return('that');
    }else{
        return($match[0]);
    }
}
print $html;
```

---

**Dynamic:**

```
$tag = 'no-glossary';
$find = 'this';
$replace = 'that';

$pattern = "/\[$tag\][ ]*\b$find\b[ ]*\[\/$tag\]|$find/"; 
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>';

$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use($find, $replace){
    if($match[0] == $find){
        return($replace);
    }else{
        return($match[0]);
    }
}, $html);

print $html;
```

Comment: ps: this won't work for `<p>Do not replace [no-glossary] lol this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>`

Comment: Hamza - this works great. Now I have two solutions. Could you comment on @Casimir-et-Hippolyte solution above. Which would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `([^\[\]])this([^\[\]])`

Of course you'll need to apply what you really need on 'this' word.

Comment: Thanks, but this resulted in the same problem as noted above. Please note that the problem occurs when the word 'this' has a space before and after the word e.g. ' this '

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b(this)\b(?!(?:(?!\[no-glossary\]).)*?\[/no-glossary\])
```

This will exclude replacing `this` if it is followed by `[/no-glossary]` except if it encounters `[no-glossary]` first.

Comment: This won't work for `<p>Do not replace this [/no-glossary] replace this.</p>`

Comment: Hi Marcellus. This pattern caused an error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'n' in eval() (line 6 of /var/www/html/websites/sites/all/modules/contrib/devel/devel.module(1285) : eval()'d code). Could you recheck your syntax please.

Comment: @user2254788 He forgot to escape a forward slash: `\b(this)\b(?!(?:(?!\[no-glossary\]).)*?\[\/no-glossary\])`

Answer (score 0):

try this it replace only `this` word

```
$pattern = '%([^\da-zA-Z]+)this([^\da-zA-Z]+)%si';
$html = '<p>Do not replace [no-glossary]this sdf[/no-glossary] thisreplace<p> replacethis.</p>replace this.</p>';
function Replace1($M){
//print_r($M);
    return $M[1]."that".$M[2];
}
$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern,"Replace1",$html);
print $html;
```

output:

```
<p>Do not replace [no-glossary]that sdf[/no-glossary] thisreplace<p> replacethis.</p>replace that.</p>
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP wants. He doesn't want to replace what's between `[no-glossary][/no-glossary]`.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, but it replaces the wrong instance! Could you try an expression that replaces the word NOT between the [no-glossary] tags but elsewhere.

Comment: @hamza-dzcyberdev you get it! Any solutions?

Comment: @user2254788 Yes, I'm still thinking, I thought of a solution but it seems that the PCRE RegEx engine doesn't support it ! So I'm hammering on a workaround !

Comment: @user2254788 see change answer